# VBA Microsoft Visio document manipulating without opening the application

Tags: vba, visio

I am working on manipulating the Visio documents from the Visual Basic 6.0. User needs to choose the input visio document.
I am using

```
Set appVisio = CreateObject("Visio.Application")
appVisio.Visible = False
```

Here the issue is, Visio Application is displaying to the user and in next line it is hiding, which makes screen flickering.
 Can we create the object without opening the visio application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use "Visio.InvisibleApp" instead of "Visio.Application" -- should work with Visio 2003 and later.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa175566%28v=office.11%29.aspx

Comment: You're welcome! Actually, according to the docs, it looks like it should even work with Visio 2000. (It was more than 10 years ago, my memories of what happened when are muddled and fuzzed by time...)